# What is the default order of execution for a php class?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make sure I understand the default behavior of a PHP Class. If no function call is specified, will the class automatically execute the public functions in order?

**Explanation:**

I'm working with a PHP Class I didn't create. There are a number of private variables set, followed by the `__construct` function, which is public.

There is no explicit call to another function in `__construct`. It merges the external config with the Class config.

The next public function is called `generateOutput()`. There is no explicit call to that function, but it is the next thing executed, according to my output log.

I'm just trying to be certain that I'm understanding the order and wasn't certain that a public function will automatically execute. I always thought `__construct` did simply because it has a specific name.

**Answer**

The external class file is required once from a php snippet and the new class instance is created. The snippet returns the output from that function.

```
require_once($classfile);
try{
    $handler = new EasyPoll($config,$lang);
    return $handler->generateOutput(); //BINGO!
}
```

Thanks for the help. It definitely got my head straight again!

Comment: Without code, you can't get a meaningful reply. But apart from the constructor, there's no magic going on when creating an object. Something definitely calls that method.

Comment: You sholud show us method's contructor, and code where you create new class instance. I guess that after `$var = new classname()`, there is call `$var->generateOutput`

Comment: That's what I thought. I will keep searching and post a reply when I figure out where it's coming from. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Found it! It's in the snippet that calls the class. I kept looking inside the class itself. `return $handler->generateOutput();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this class inheriting from another one? In that case that might make sense, because the extended class is not calling `generateOutput()`, but the parent is (and you didn't override that behavior).

Answer (score 1):

There must be something you didn't notice. No methods except `__construct` are (by default) called when class is created. However, consider following scenario:

```
class A {
    private $b = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = new B($this);
    }
    public function fn() {
        echo "HA!<br />\n";
    }
 }
 class B {
    public function __construct(A $owner) {
        $owner->fn();
    }
 }
 //Code:
 $a = new A();  //Outputs "HA!"
```

What I'm trying to demonstrate is, that the code you didn't write may be obscure and do lot's of *magic*.

Another posibility:

```
class A {
    private $b = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->fn();
    }
    public function fn() {
        echo "HA!<br />\n";
    }
 }
 class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
 }
 //And the execution:
 $b = new B(); //Again outputs A
```